# login with error 'Call to a member function prepare() on null'

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel makes me crazy showing the next following error:
[image]

The error happens when login controller is triggered.

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);
        // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
        // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
        // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
        $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();

        if ($throttles && $lockedOut = $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);
       // $credentials['type']=1;
       // return $credentials;die;
        if (Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
            return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
        }

        // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
        // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
        // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
        if ($throttles && ! $lockedOut) {
            $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
        }

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }
```

Seems like is an error related to the database though the login service is managed by an API that works well. I don't know why this error happens. I'm really newbie to Laravel so if anyone can guide me I will thank.

**User Model**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','phone','photo','first_name', 'contact_name', 'address', 'phone_number', 'fiscal_number', 'about_us',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function subscription()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\EmployerSubscription','employer_id','_id');
    }
    public function jobseekers()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\JobSeekers');
    }


    public function experience()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Experience')->where('status',true);
    }

}
```

Comment: show us your user model

Comment: are you using mongodb?

Comment: @SapneshNaik Yes, mongodb is the database

Comment: @Sohel0415 There's the user model Sohel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default **User** model is extending **Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model**, where it has to extend **Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model** to work with **MongoDB**. By changing the User model in **app/User.php**, this can be resolved. Change your user model to following-

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
class User extends \Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model implements
AuthenticatableContract,
AuthorizableContract,
CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword, Notifiable;

   /**
    * The attributes that are mass assignable.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

   /**
    * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
    *
    * @var array
    */
   protected $fillable = [
       'name', 'email', 'password','phone','photo','first_name', 'contact_name', 'address', 'phone_number', 'fiscal_number', 'about_us',
    ];

   /**
    * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
    *
    * @var array
    */
   protected $hidden = [
       'password', 'remember_token',
   ];

   public function subscription()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Models\EmployerSubscription','employer_id','_id');
   }
   public function jobseekers()
   {
       return $this->hasOne('App\Models\JobSeekers');
   }


   public function experience()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Experience')->where('status',true);
   }
}
```

Comment: Now error goes -> FatalThrowableError in EloquentUserProvider.php line 130:
Class '\App\Models\User' not found

Comment: I don't know why, That class actually exist

Comment: try composer dump-autoload, before that make sure folders name and file name are accurate

Comment: and run php artisan config:clear, php artisan cache:clear, php artisan view:clear

Comment: erasing config can help you in this regard

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162612/discussion-between-cesar-jr-rodriguez-and-sohel0415).

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that login service is managed by API, but as i can see you have used laravel Auth service provider for authentication. Please check database settings in your project .env file. if issue still persist kindly follow below steps.

1. composer dump-autoload
2. php artisan cache:clear
3. php artisan view:clear
4. php artisan config:clear

and restart your server. Hope that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to User model and add the following;

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;

class User extends Eloquent implements AuthenticatableContract,
```